# smooth full width continuous dual testimonial slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, bootstrap-5

I'm looking for a testimonial slider similar to https://userway.org/.
Can anyone suggest it plz?
Or guide me to a post if there is any.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/get-started) for that.

here is a simple example

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      loop:true,
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
        pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
        disableOnInteraction: false
      },
      speed:9000
    });
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiperDir", {
      loop:true,
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
        pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
        disableOnInteraction: false
      },
      speed:9000
    });
```

```css
 html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 48%;
      margin-bottom:1rem;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div dir="rtl" class="swiper mySwiperDir">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. How about the pause and play button for the sliders animation?

Comment: you can use swiper.autoplay.start() and swiper.autoplay.stop() for that. here is swiper api page https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api . it is all here.